# Border Selection in blender like in 3ds max

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

In 3ds max we have:
-vertex selection
-edge selection
-**border selection**
-face selection
-element selection
I wanted to know if an option/add-on like **border selection** exist it will be a time saver for selection gap in mesh and then bridge them

Comment: hello, could you please show what it means with a screenshot?

Comment: Agree with moonboots, I'd suggest explain what it does in max so we can *all* help finding what you're looking for. To me it sounds like: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html#edge-loops-all-boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a particular border:

If you <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> select an edge on a border, it will select up to non-loop poles. Still holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd>, a second click will extend the selection to the whole border:

[image]

If you want to select all borders, then select one border edge, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge* will find the rest:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you hold alt and click an edge it will select the whole loop. it stops at poles (vertices with 5+ edges attached), but you can hold shift and just select more edge loops. I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Border selection is the open, continuous edges of an object. Such as a hole in the face of a plane, or the outer edges of the plane.

[image: 3ds Max Border Selection Tool]